# Constructing a procedural DSL based on extensible Java methods

Tags: java, json, clojure, velocity, dsl

**The question**

How does one create a procedural DSL based on an extensible suite of Java methods that are invoked during the runtime?

**More context**

*Example script*

The following script is a contrived example, but one that I hope captures the point.

```
result = $add($vector3(1, 2, 3), $vector3(1, 0, 1))
result.normalize()
$log(result)
return result
```

The key is that the DSL is essentially built out of an extensible suite of Java methods that are invoked during interpretation of the script. Ideally this set of allowed methods would be dictated by the engine.

Built-in support for conditionals, loops, primitives, and comments would be helpful.

*Languages that accomplish something similar*

1. **Apache Velocity** provides extension capabilities through the addition of user-defined objects to the template context. These objects, and the methods scoped to them, are accessible from the Velocity templates by their user-defined name. For related information, see http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html and the discussion of methods. However, Velocity is a templating engine, not meant for procedural scripts.
2. **Clojure** also provides similar functionality (https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop.) However, the Clojure syntax is less than intuitive.
3. **Groovy** is a very powerful Java-based scripting language. In fact, it seems too powerful for my needs. I specifically do not want the full power of Java at the hands of these scripts. There seem to be extensions as in Groovy Sandbox discussed here ([How to block access to some classes, when executing groovy scripts from java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017584/how-to-block-access-to-some-classes-when-executing-groovy-scripts-from-java)) but it seems like there must be a language in which this simplicity is a first-class feature.

Comment: This is a nice question, but it's extremely broad. As it says in the help center, _If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much._ And if the question is "How do I create my own domain-specific language" an entire book is not too far off.  That said, take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java  I don't know if it's quite what you're looking for, but it's at least one you can add to your list of similar technologies.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what problem you are trying to solve, that is not already solved by Java or Clojure. A DSL can mean so many things... Do you mean to embed a small programming language interpreter inside your program, to let the user customize your program? If you want to implement your own interpreter, I would start with a stack-oriented language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_evaluation_algorithm

Comment: Greenspun's tenth rule says any "Any sufficiently complicated C or Fortran program contains an ad-hoc, informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of Common Lisp."  So a fully implemented language like clojure could be an ideal DSL.

Your custom DSL in clojure may look like :

    Vector Definition : `(vector [1,2,3])`
    add vectors : `(concat [1,2,3] [1,0,1])`
    Define value : `(def result (concat [1,2,3] [1,0,1])`
    normalize result : `(normalize result)`
    Log result : `(log (normalize (result))`

Comment: @jas and pankajdoharey: Thank you for the clarifying comments. I do not want to answer the general question. Perhaps a better phrasing would be: "Is there a framework which allows me to quickly generate a DSL based on Java interop but without the syntactic issues (from a non-technical point of view) of Clojure?" I am now 99% certain this does not exist, but it feels like an obvious product gap.